# SOAP Web Service Client error, While consuming the service

Tags: soap, axis, soap-client

I am getting this error while using SOAP web service client with axis 1. I had created stub from the wsdl file and tried to consume it then I got this error. wsdl is given to me by someone else.

> error in msg parsing: xml was empty, did't parse!

below is the error message and stack trace for the same. Anyone can help.?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the javax.activation.DataHandler issue you must add the [JavaBeans Activation Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-135046.html) activation.jar in your classpath.

In order to fix the javax.mail.internet.mimeMultipart issue you must add the [Java Mail API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) mail.jar in your classpath.

The warning messages printed in your console shows that the above jars are not in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

There are several common reasons to receive the message:

```
error in msg parsing: xml was empty, did't parse!
```

The most obvious is that no message was sent.  If you have some way of inspecting your transport channel, that would be worth looking at.

Also, the xml message could have been sent in an unexpected character set, e.g. A header declares it to be "Utf-8" but it is really "Win-1252", sometimes you can get away with that if you only use 7-bit ASCII characters, but anything in the 8-bit plane will cause it to bomb.

Also, the xml message could have had a byte order mark unexpectedly inserted at the beginning of the message.

Also, the xml message might not have the document declaration ( starting in the first byte of the message, that violates the specification, and often causes parsers to puke and claim that no message was found.

All things considered with this error message, the parser was not able to find a valid xml message that it could parse, so it didn't.  You need to grab the data on the transport channel and figure out what exactly is wrong to resolve the issue.